# Firebase firestore: how to create timestamp from seconds in Kotlin for Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a firebase firestore timestamp object by passing number of seconds to it, but it is not working.

Here's the code snippet.

```
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp
import com.google.firebase.firestore.*


var timeStampString:String = "1438910477"
var t = timeStampString.toLong()
var ts = Timestamp(t)
```

I am getting error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied
<Init>(Parcel) defined in com.google.firebase.Timestamp
<Init>(Date) defined in com.google.firebase.Timestamp
```

I am passing number as the parameter as mentioned in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html#constructor). But it is expecting "Parcel" or "Date".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the API documentation you linked to, the constructor requires two number parameters, not one.  If you don't have a component in nanoseconds to pass, then pass 0:

```
var timeStampString:String = "1438910477"
var t = timeStampString.toLong()
var ts = Timestamp(t, 0)
```

But, why parse a string to a number when you can code the number directly:

```
var t = 1438910477
var ts = Timestamp(t, 0)
```

Comment: Oh, I feel so silly now. Thanks for pointing it out. It is working. I don't know why I felt that second parameter must be optional. Yeah, that string to number part was extraneous here. Just that in my code I am getting a string that I need to convert to a number.